# How can I convert from numbers to characters?

Tags: c#

I have an array of numbers in C#. The numbers range from one to ten. I would like to just show letters for example a letter "b" instead of the number 2.

Is there an easy way for me to do this.

Hope there is.

Maria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just build a mapping array:

```
char[] chars = "abcdefghij".ToCharArray();
```

and just use:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length;i++) {
    int num = arr[i]; // 1 to 10
    Console.Write(chars[num-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your letters of choice in a string and then index it with the number.

```
char character = "abcdefghij"[number - 1];
```

If you'd like to convert the entire array at once, you can easily do it using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
string letters = "abcdefghij";
int[] numbers = new [] { 1, 5, 2, 7 };
string converted = new String(numbers.Select(n => letters[n - 1]).ToArray());
```

This takes advantage of the [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx), which allows you to create a new string from an array of `char`.